# How do I update a state upon a new response from API?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to update my currently played track using Spotify's API.
Currently, I am pulling the correct song, but when I change the track, the current song still displays.

Is there any way to have my state wait for a new response, and then update, rather than having to have a setInterval run every second?

I've tried using setInterval which works but requires my state to run every second to detect changes, rather than just waiting for the response from the API to change.

This is my  state where I'm pulling from the Spotify API:

```
getNowPlaying() {
    setInterval(() => {
      spotifyApi.getMyCurrentPlaybackState().then(response => {
        this.setState({
          nowPlaying: {
            name: response.item.name,
            image: response.item.album.images[0].url,
            artists_name: response.item.artists[0].name,
            artists_id: response.item.artists[0].id
          }
        });
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
```

This is where I display it:

```
<div className="current-user">
     <img
      alt="currentuser"
      className="rounded-image"
      src={this.state.currentInfo.display_image}
      style={{ height: 150 }}
      />
      <div>{this.state.currentInfo.display_name}</div>
   </div>
```

I am expecting to be able to constantly check to see if a new response was sent, but it doesn't update automatically.

Answer (score -1):

You should pick up on the 'Next Track' button click and update your state after you receive the API response. When the user clicks next, I assume you are sending an API request to Spotify to grab which song is next, it is at this point which you should update your state.

This pseudo code/example does not use the Spotify API, but the logic should be similar.

[CodePen Mirror](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/aewwBo?editors=1010)

```js
class ApiFetcher extends React.Component {
  state = {
    apiData: "",
    track: 1
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getNextFromApi();
  }

  getNextFromApi = () => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${this.state.track}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          track: this.state.track + 1,
          apiData: json
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.getNextFromApi}>Next Track</button>
        {this.state.apiData ? (
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.apiData, null, 2)}</pre>
        ) : (
          <p>Unable to get next track..</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <ApiFetcher />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback! Will this only work if the user clicks the Next Track button? What if a song is over and goes to the next song without the user clicking Next Track, how will the app know to update the response?

Comment: (1/2) As a disclaimer - just wanted to get it out of the way... I do not have any experience with the Spotify REST API...  Ok....so...are you wanting to stream Spotify on your own site?  If so, their REST API will not be of much help to you.. All their REST API allows you to do is gather data about certain metrics as well as change songs in a playlist - things like that. In short, **in their REST API**, they do not seem to have any callbacks which inform you when a song has changed, so you will need to manually check for this.

Comment: (2/2) If you are wanting to stream songs and control them yourself, it does look like they have a new-ish feature that allows you to stream music from their API **(NOT their traditional REST API)**.. It appears their ***Web Playback SDK*** allows you to pick up on events, like song changes, which would allow you the opportunity to update your state.. More on the REST API [can be found here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/) .... More on the Web Playback SDK [can be found here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-playback-sdk/)